# New install of 17.10 inconsistant DNS issues

Tags: apt, 17.10

**Update:**

There was an issue with webup8 but bigger than that is the fact it inconsistantly has issues with DNS
The browser also cant find websites then if I refresh loads like normal.

When doing apt it sits on [Working]0% for 30s before it kicks off.

Any ideas?

New install of 17.10 on an iMac

Browser working fine with wifi but cannot update with apt-get have been trying for 2 days.

Have tried a different mirror same issue

The reason given is not consistant this the first time

```
$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for andrew: 
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                               
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease                                                                                    
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease                                                                                 
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                       
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease                                                                                
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease                                                           
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu artful InRelease                          
  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Hit:9 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu artful InRelease                
Reading package lists... Done                           
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/dists/artful/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This the second:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                               
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu artful InRelease                                                                                 
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                              
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease                                                           
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease [81.7 kB]           
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease [72.2 kB]                                                                                             
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease [78.6 kB]                                                                                              
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu artful InRelease [15.4 kB]                                                                                   
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu artful InRelease                                                                                             
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 531EE72F4C9D234C
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                           
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu artful InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 531EE72F4C9D234C
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu artful InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

This the third:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                               
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease                                                                                     
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                                     
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu artful InRelease [15.4 kB]                                                
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu artful InRelease                
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 531EE72F4C9D234C
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease [81.7 kB]                
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease [72.2 kB]              
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease [78.6 kB]               
Hit:9 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu artful InRelease                                                                                                              
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu artful InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 531EE72F4C9D234C
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu artful InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

The only thing consistant is that it never succeeds :(

Here is my sources:

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score -1):

webupd8 isn't active since end of 2017 so the repos like most of them or all are inactive and may cause problems as You've encountered

Comment: A worthwhile comment but unrelated to to unresolvable hosts and missing repository signature keys.